# Normalize over range with min excluded

Tags: r, normalization

I know how to normalize between 0 and 1, this is usually done with a function like the following:

```
function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
```

But now I would like to normalize so that the result is uniformly distributed over (0,1], i.e. 0 should be excluded. In the above formula, it is included. How can I do this? Test data would be for example:

```
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer does not have to be given in R.

Comment: Since you cannot assure a uniform distribution unless the input is uniformly distributed, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you asserting all inputs will be uniformly distributed?  Could you supply the intended output for the `test` data you supplied so we can better understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: This question is not about any underlying distribution. It is common practice in machine learning to standardize variables before optimization.

Comment: It may be a more appropriate question though for https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I tried to edit your question, so that it could be reopened: https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/188767. My edit was rejected by @.gung on these grounds: "*this will bump the thread into the reopen queue w/o it being reopenable, taking an opportunity away from the OP.*" If you agree with my suggested edit, could you make the edit yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Original: **excluding one** (quick and dirty)*

A simple

```
myfunc <- function(x){(x - min(x))/( max(x) + (10e-10) - min(x) )}
```

would do the trick. To check, run:

```
options(digits = 10)
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

> myfunc(test)
> [1] 0.0000000000 0.2499999999 0.4999999999 0.7499999998 0.9999999997
```

versus

```
> [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

without the small offset.

Set the offset smaller in actual code: the `10e-10` is for illustration purposes.

---

*Update: **excluding zero** (quick and dirty)*

Just use:

```
> 1 - myfunc(-test)
> [1] 2.500000207e-10 2.500000002e-01 5.000000001e-01 7.500000001e-01 1.000000000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know how to exclude the min? I am also not sure if there is not a 'cleaner' way somehow. Note: I cannot upvote you bec I dont have enough reputation. I would like to wait a bit longer if there is an alternative way/solution.